# Unable to read hidden field value in ascx.cs page

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a hidden field like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="showHideFlag" runat="server" />
```

I am assigning some value to this hidden field in java script as follows:

```
function controlSearchBar() {
     if ($("#MainContent_ProjectListControl_searchBar").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showHideFlag")[0].value = "showing";
        } else {
        $("#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showHideFlag")[0].value = "hiding";
        }
      }
```

I am trying to read this hidden field in ascx.cs page as follows:

```
string hdnValue = this.showHideFlag.Value;
```

But this hdnValue is not getting the value of that hidden field.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: Have you checked your result at runtime, that the input field has got the target value? You can do that with Firebug in FF browser.

Comment: Yes I have checked. I am able to get the value in java script but when I am  trying to read the same in ascx.cs page it is not getting

Comment: on what event you are accessing the hidden field value?

Comment: Then please post also your html source code. Probply you used a wrong method for submi the data.

Comment: $("#MainContent_ProjectListControl_showHideFlag")[0].val("showing"); Try this syntax and see if you can get the value in code behind

Comment: I tried all this. still not able to get the value

Answer (score 0):

Hidden as `type="hidden"`

```
$("#MainContent_ProjectListControl_searchBar").attr('type') == 'hidden'
```

Hidden as `display: none`

```
$("#MainContent_ProjectListControl_searchBar").is(":hidden")
```

Comment: How can I read the value of this hidden field in ascx.cs  page?

Answer (score 0):

> Gets the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET.

```
<asp:Label ID="SelectedSport" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ClientID="showHideFlag">
```

**javascript**

```
$("#showHideFlag").text("found");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you can get the value in javascript So I think the the problem is with the hidden field. try to set value by Client id as follows-

```
 var hd = document.getElementById('<%= showHideFlag.ClientID%>');
            hd.value = "hi";
```

And my another question is in which event you are accessing value? because If you are setting value in javascript and accessing in Page Load event then it will not work because first of all Page load event  gets fired and then Javascript function executes.